# "" is not a valid CIDR block: invalid CIDR address

Tags: terraform

I have a VPC defined in terraform:

```
//vpc.tf
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

And I am trying to create a security group:

```
// securityGroup.tf
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  ingress {
    description      = "TLS from VPC"
    from_port        = 443
    to_port          = 443
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.my_vpc.cidr_block]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.my_vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
  }
  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
}
```

However, when I run `terraform plan` I get the error `Error: "" is not a valid CIDR block: invalid CIDR address:`

I thought that the `cidr_block` defined in my vpc would be available to the securityGroup, but that seems to not be the case. How do I correctly reference the `cidr_block` from my vpc?

Full error output:

```
│ Error: "" is not a valid CIDR block: invalid CIDR address: 
│ 
│   with module.shared.aws_security_group.allow_tls,
│   on modules/shared/securityGroup.tf line 1, in resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls":
│    1: resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
```

Comment: Which specific line is Terraform saying is the issue? How about showing the full error message in your question?

Comment: Good call, added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't configured your VPC with any IPV6 addresses. So this line in your security group should be deleted:

```
ipv6_cidr_blocks = [aws_vpc.my_vpc.ipv6_cidr_block]
```